# Novelty SQL code

Tags: sql

Okay, I know this is a bit silly but can someone help me?

I'm getting a custom mug printed for someone and want to know if the below makes sense? Is the SQL accurate or is there anyway to improve it or the formatting/naming conventions? They know certainly know SQL.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.MUG
    SELECT Tea FROM dbo.KITCHEN
    WHERE Milk_Type = 'Semi Skimmed'
    AND Sugar_Count = 0;
```

Comment: This should be a union query for tea and milk.

Answer (score 0):

If you are learning SQL, I would recommend that you write the query as:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.MUG(<column name here>)
    SELECT k.Tea
    FROM dbo.KITCHEN k
    WHERE k.Milk_Type = 'Semi Skimmed' AND k.Sugar_Count = 0;
```

The most important change is listing the columns after the `INSERT`.  I also think each clause in the `SELECT` should start on its own line.

Comment: Thank you, my SQL knowledge is limited. Would the AND clause need to be on a separate line?

Comment: it can be on the same line but just for a cleaner coding where in the future you need to debug it or add another conditions or sub-queries, you will be able to check it easily

Comment: @NewToThis . . . `AND` is not a clause.  It is a boolean operator.  I do not start lines with boolean operators.